# Error install R package. Cannot find -lgmop -lquadmath

Tags: r, linux, centos7, devtools

I am fairly new to R, so excuse me if this is a straight forward question.

I am using a cluster (CentOS7) where I installed R (v. 4.0.3) using miniconda, along with a bunch of other tools I need.
Afterwards I used the "build in" R way to install packages, i.e. using `install.packages("package_name")`.
For some packages, e.g. `ggplot2` this worked without a problem. However, when I try to install other packages, such as `vegan`, it fails with the following error message

```
/home/bq_uell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/7.5.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lgomp
/home/bq_uell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/7.5.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lquadmath
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Installing [binutils](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/binutils) did not help.
If anyone could point out what I am doing wrong, or what I am missing, I would be very happy!

Cheers!

EDIT:
This is the entire error message:

```
* installing *source* package ‘vegan’ ...
** package ‘vegan’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -I"/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -I/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib   -fpic  -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/r-base_1603051729662/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.3 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c data2hill.c -o data2hill.o
x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -fopenmp -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/r-base_1603051729662/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.3 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c decorana.f -o decorana.o
x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -I"/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -I/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib   -fpic  -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/r-base_1603051729662/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.3 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c getF.c -o getF.o
x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -I"/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -I/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib   -fpic  -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/r-base_1603051729662/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.3 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c goffactor.c -o goffactor.o
x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -I"/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -I/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib   -fpic  -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/r-base_1603051729662/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.3 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c init.c -o init.o
x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -fopenmp -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/r-base_1603051729662/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.3 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c monoMDS.f -o monoMDS.o
x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -I"/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -I/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib   -fpic  -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/r-base_1603051729662/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.3 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c nestedness.c -o nestedness.o
x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -fopenmp -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/r-base_1603051729662/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.3 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c ordering.f -o ordering.o
x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -I"/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -I/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib   -fpic  -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/r-base_1603051729662/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.3 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c pnpoly.c -o pnpoly.o
x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -I"/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -I/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib   -fpic  -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/r-base_1603051729662/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.3 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c stepacross.c -o stepacross.o
x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -I"/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -I/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib   -fpic  -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/r-base_1603051729662/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.3 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c vegdist.c -o vegdist.o
x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -shared -L/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib/R/lib -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-rpath,/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib -L/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib -o vegan.so data2hill.o decorana.o getF.o goffactor.o init.o monoMDS.o nestedness.o ordering.o pnpoly.o stepacross.o vegdist.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lgomp -lquadmath -lpthread -lgfortran -lm -lgomp -lquadmath -lpthread -L/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib/R/lib -lR
/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/7.5.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lgomp
/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/7.5.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lquadmath
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib/R/share/make/shlib.mk:10: vegan.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘vegan’
* removing ‘/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib/R/library/vegan’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpeFtKBY/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  unable to load shared object '/home/bq_nhirschmuell/miniconda3/envs/antigen.garnish/lib/R/modules//R_X11.so':
  libXt.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2: In install.packages("vegan") :
  installation of package ‘vegan’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

- The first one is the name of the libraries. Search what is the exact name of the libraries installed. when you use `-lgomp` the linker will search `libgomp.so` (or libgomp.a  if you are linkins statically). If you find only `libgomp.so.something` there are two possibilities:
  *create a symbolic link with `ln -s libgomp.so.something libgomp.so`
  *or link against `-l:libgomp.so.something`
- The second possibility is the path. add `-v` to your link command and verify that the path to libgomp.so is present in the list of search path use by collect2. If it not present because the installation folder is not part of your link default research folders, add it with the `-L` option.

You need to do the same for the other library.

Comment: unfortunately, this did not work. installing lgomp and lquadmath via `sudo yum install` worked fine, but the same error as above still appears..

Comment: Could you add the compilation command which generate the error . if possible with verbose option `-v`.

Comment: I edited my original quesiton to include the error message

Comment: did you succeeded to link your executable?

Comment: I think that the problem is with the path. I can find `libgomp.so` in my conda environment under the `lib` directory. I am unsure how to use the `-L` option in my case, because I am not directly calling the commands, but instead `install.packages()` does. 
Any chance you know if I can like globally change the path in which `install.packages()` is looking for?

Comment: may be you can use ``configure.args = c(.....)` to set the LDFLAGS, however did teh libgomp.so and libquadmath.so  are present in a different directory from the other libs . Since it is not complaining about the other libs. if so may be you can create a symlink to you so files in the directory containing the other so files founded. can you check also if libgomp.so have the same ELF format as the so files founded